# Create an Elasticsearch template with NEST - documentation out of date

Tags: c#, nest

We're trying to add an Elasticsearch template to set all guids to not analyzed fields, but the sample code on the nest website seems to be out of date.

Our aim is to use a bit of recursion and reflection to analyze the properties and then add all guids as not analysed properties in the index template.

While attempting to follow the code on this page, there were just too many compile time issues to move forward.

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/templates.html

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will point you the way.

```
var templateName = "name";
var indexNameTemplate = "te*";

var response = client.PutTemplate(templateName, t => t
    .Template(indexNameTemplate)
    .AddMapping<>(...);
```